# i have a problem with flutter : 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter, cmd

i'm facing a problem with my flutter, when i write in my command 'flutter doctor' i get :

```
where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

Then when i run the command as administrator, and wrote 'flutter doctor' :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1256], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc4)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[☠] Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
      about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    X ProcessException: Failed to find "reg" in the search path.
        Command: reg

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and in android studio i get:

```
Error: PowerShell executable not found.                         
       Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.
```

what should i do ?

when i wrote set path in command i got :

```
C:\Users\DELL>set path
path=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\php;C:\dart-sdk\bin;C:\flutter\bin;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: You've broken your `%PATH%` variable. Have you got a command in using `set` with `path`? If not, please open a Command Prompt window, type `set path`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and post the output into your question area, using [edit]. If you have, please post the `set` command you're using with `path` in it.

Comment: Yes, I was correct, you've modified your PATH variable, and in doing so, broken it. If you want to fix it, you should begin by posting the output from these two commands. `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path`, and `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCU\Environment /V Path`. You should also post the version of Microsoft Windows you are using.

Comment: thank you @Compo i just fixed it and now the output is correct

Comment: You haven't what you've done is only part correct, it is not fully correct.

Comment: BTW, you could also retrieve your Windows version using the same method, `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V ProductName`

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the answer:
i went to env => System variables => path (if u don't have one create one) => i added the path of :

```
C:\flutter\bin;
C:\Windows\System32;
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

and now it works

```
C:\Users\DELL>flutter doctor
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                      14.1s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1256], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc4)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

oh, so apparently it not a vey correct answer, so the asked output are:

```
C:\Users\DELL>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    Path    REG_SZ    C:\flutter\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
```

and

```
C:\Users\DELL>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCU\Environment /V Path

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\php;C:\dart-sdk\bin;C:\flutter\bin;
```

and for the

```
C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin
```

i guess i will just delete it cause it an old one and i don't use it.

So after the suggested modification the output looks like this :

```
C:\Users\DELL>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SYSTEMDRIVE%\flutter\bin;C:\Windows\System32;%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin;%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\cmd;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH;%SYSTEMDRIVE%\php;%SYSTEMDRIVE%\dart-sdk\bin;
```

and :

```
C:\Users\DELL>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCU\Environment /V Path

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\anaconda3;%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\bin;%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\php;C:\dart-sdk\bin;C:\flutter\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
```

Comment: This is still not correct, please provide the answers to my requests in my comment.

Comment: You will need to take special care with the location/position of `C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin`, because if it contains the same executables as in `C:\flutter\bin`, the ones in the ```\Downloads\``` location will no longer be used. Previously that location came first, but now you've modified it, it no longer will. Take a look at the output from `path` entered in the Command Prompt, and note the new order, _(and possible duplicate of `C:\flutter\bin` too)_! When `%PATH%` is searched for an exectuable file match, only the first found is used.

Comment: Also in your submitted solution above, `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` is not a valid entry!

Comment: Asuming you're using Windows 10, the content of your System Path in the GUI should be these, in this order: `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`, `%SYSTEMROOT%`, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Wbem`, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH`, `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\php`, `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\dart-sdk\bin`, `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\flutter\bin`, `%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin`, and `%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\cmd`.

Comment: The content of your User Path in the GUI, should be thiese, in this order: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`, `%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3`, `%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin`, `%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin`, `%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\bin`, `%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Scripts`, and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Comment: And as previously mentioned, you'll need to reconsider if you're wishing to use `C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin`, at all, and if so, you should probably move its location to somewhere accessible to all users, and then insert that location in the System environment Path, before, or in replacement of `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\flutter\bin`.

Comment: oh okay thank u so much for correcting me, i will post the output that u asked for

Comment: Ndia Nadou, apologies for not replying, but I have just found this as part of a search for something, and was unaware that you hade responded. When you wish to notify me of a change, or reply to me directly within a comment, you need to prefix my member name with a `@` character, and I'll be notified. Your updated information does not match what I posted in my comments, where I provided everything your should have under each entry in your GUI, and the order I think you should use them in. You still have entries I did not mention, i.e. some need removing, and you really should change the order.